# Matplotlib bar chart in a wx Frame instead of a new window

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a simple wxFrame and two panels in it. i want one of the panels to show a matplotlib bar chart. I learnt to use the chart, but the show() function that I use gives me the chart in a new window.

```
 import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
import os
import Image
import pylab as p

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        #txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        button =wx.Button(self, label="Save", pos=(200, 325))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels)

class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        fig=p.figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        x=[1,2,3]
        y=[4,6,3]
        ax.bar(x,y)
        p.show()

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Panel Switch",
                          size=(800,600))

        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_two = PanelTwo(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        switch_panels_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,
                                                  "Switch Panels",
                                                  "Some text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onSwitchPanels,
                  switch_panels_menu_item)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSwitchPanels(self, event):

        if self.panel_one.IsShown():
           self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
           self.panel_one.Hide()
           self.panel_two.Show()
        else:
           self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
           self.panel_one.Show()
           self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

What happens is that I get the chart in a new matplotlib window and when I close that, my frame appears. I need the chart to be in the second panel of the frame.

I tried reading [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel) , but did not quite help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pyplot` functions you are using (`p.figure`) have the primary purpose of taking care of all the GUI details (which works at cross purposes to what you want).  What you want to to is embed `matplotlib` in your pre-existing gui.  For how to do this, see these [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/).

This code is pulled from [embedding_in_wx2.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html) to protect against link-rot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
An example of how to use wx or wxagg in an application with the new
toolbar - comment out the setA_toolbar line for no toolbar
"""
# Used to guarantee to use at least Wx2.8
import wxversion
wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
from numpy import arange, sin, pi

import matplotlib

# uncomment the following to use wx rather than wxagg
#matplotlib.use('WX')
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas

# comment out the following to use wx rather than wxagg
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wx

class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,
                         'CanvasFrame',size=(550,350))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColour("WHITE"))
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.canvas.draw()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = App(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This works on the frame. But I am looking for to embed the chart inside one of the panels. And Bar chart at that. I tried your code inside a panel, but failed. I used the pylot because of my inability to bring up bar charts.

Comment: I can't do anything with 'it failed'.  You should edit your question with _exactly_ what you tried or open a new question.  To get bar plots instead of lines, just change `self.axes.plot(...)` -> `self.axes.bar(...)`.

Comment: Actually I tweaked in a bit and changed the plot to bar like u said and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: glad hear! Sorry I was snippy, haven't had enough coffee yet today.

Comment: No problem. Helped a lot. I am just learning python and trying to get a lot of plots in a single window. :) I need coffee too. Cheers.