# Can I get imshow() like behaviour in a wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm new to wxpython but have been a matplotlib user for some time now. I am developing a wxpython app in which I would like to have a simple frame with a single panel (actually, a wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas instance). In the panel I want to show some data, which is in the form of a binary array (called imarr), like this one:

[image: example of the data I would like to display]
The array will always be of shape (64,N), and N can vary between about 400 and 1200 (I can sort out the panel sizing myself).

To do this in matplotlib I would use something like:

```
fig=figure(figsize=(12,2))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(0,63)
ax.set_xlim(0,imarr.shape[0])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
matplotlib.imshow(imarr)
```

But I'm completely lost in wxpython. I have been looking into wx.lib.plot, but apart from the nice line and marker plotting capabilities, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to imshow (or pcolor).

One (ugly) solution I have is to use matplotlib as above to create a png image and then use some wx magic to display the image on a panel (please set me straight if this won't be easy).

I'd much prefer to do it from within wxpython, for portability and general tidiness. Any advice on how to display a binary array on a wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas (or a more generic wx.Panel) would be very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you combine wxPython and matplotlib together? wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas has limited functionality comparing to matplotlib. Have a look at an example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel%20answer) and an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/mathtext_wx.html?highlight=wxpython) from the matplotlib documentation. Sorry that I didn't answer exactly what you are asking for but I think this is the right way to go.

Comment: Yes, this approach works very nicely; I wasn't aware that it was so straightforward. Thanks for your help.