# MatPlotLib: How to make a simple plot as a pop up?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pandas, ipython

I am using Ipython and pandas to create a Series of numbers.

```
 temperature_series = filtered_df['Daily Change'].cumsum()
```

I am then doing:

```
 plot = temperature_series .plot(marker    ='o',\
                                 linestyle ='-', \
                                 color     = 'red', \
                                 title     = 'Cumulative Change',\
                                 figsize   = (15,6))
```

and in Ipython I am getting a nice plot. I am trying to create a simple GUI using tkinter which will just open a window displaying the plot. How is this usually done pythonically? It doesn't need to necessarily use tkinter, I am using a windows 7 machine and I think it can also be done using tempfile-->save figure--->open figure.

Comment: I think you should use wxPython, and then you can do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `wxPython` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel)), but if you want to use `Tkinter` there are some examples on the `matplotlib` website [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html).

Comment: Thank you, the examples helped alot!