# how to combine wxPython, matplotlib and Pyopengl

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, pyopengl

Hi so I currently have an application whereby I have a window displaying a matplotlib graph.

i.e. such as this:

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    fr = wx.Frame(None, title='test')
    panel = CanvasPanel(fr)
    panel.draw()
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741760/1800665

What I would like to do is have two canvas's in this one panel, the left side showing a figure in a matplotlib canvas and the right side showing a shape on an opengl canvas.

I have the following code to draw a cube in an opengl canvas in wxpython:

```
import wx
import sys
from wx import glcanvas
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

class MyCanvasBase(glcanvas.GLCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        glcanvas.GLCanvas.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.init = False
        self.context = glcanvas.GLContext(self)

        # initial mouse position
        self.lastx = self.x = 30
        self.lasty = self.y = 30
        self.size = None
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # Do nothing, to avoid flashing on MSW.

    def OnSize(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.DoSetViewport)
        event.Skip()

    def DoSetViewport(self):
        size = self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        self.SetCurrent(self.context)
        glViewport(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.SetCurrent(self.context)
        if not self.init:
            self.InitGL()
            self.init = True
        self.OnDraw()

    def OnMouseDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        self.x, self.y = self.lastx, self.lasty = evt.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, evt):
        self.ReleaseMouse()

    def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            self.lastx, self.lasty = self.x, self.y
            self.x, self.y = evt.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh(False)

class CubeCanvas(MyCanvasBase):
    def InitGL(self):
        # set viewing projection
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glFrustum(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0)

        # position viewer
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -2.0)

        # position object
        glRotatef(self.y, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glRotatef(self.x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

    def OnDraw(self):
        # clear color and depth buffers
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        # draw six faces of a cube
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0,-1.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0,-1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glEnd()

        if self.size is None:
            self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        w, h = self.size
        w = max(w, 1.0)
        h = max(h, 1.0)
        xScale = 180.0 / w
        yScale = 180.0 / h
        glRotatef((self.y - self.lasty) * yScale, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef((self.x - self.lastx) * xScale, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        self.SwapBuffers()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class RunDemoApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)

    def OnInit(self):
        canvasClass = eval('CubeCanvas')

        cx = 0

        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'CubeCanvas', size=(400,400), pos=(cx,400))
        canvasClass(frame) # CubeCanvas(frame) or ConeCanvas(frame); frame passed to         MyCanvasBase
        frame.Show(True)

        self.frame = frame
        return True

    def OnExitApp(self, evt):
        self.frame.Close(True)

    def OnCloseFrame(self, evt):
        if hasattr(self, "window") and hasattr(self.window, "ShutdownDemo"):
            self.window.ShutdownDemo()
        evt.Skip()

app = RunDemoApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

taken from and adapted to remove the button panel and cone options: http://wiki.wxpython.org/GLCanvas%20update

I have been playing about and researching for quite a while and I'm finding it really difficult to understand how to mix these two canvases and display them in one frame so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code needs polishing but it works.

```
import wx
import sys
from wx import glcanvas
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

class MyCanvasBase(glcanvas.GLCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        glcanvas.GLCanvas.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.init = False
        self.context = glcanvas.GLContext(self)

        # initial mouse position
        self.lastx = self.x = 30
        self.lasty = self.y = 30
        self.size = None
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # Do nothing, to avoid flashing on MSW.

    def OnSize(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.DoSetViewport)
        event.Skip()

    def DoSetViewport(self):
        size = self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        self.SetCurrent(self.context)
        glViewport(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.SetCurrent(self.context)
        if not self.init:
            self.InitGL()
            self.init = True
        self.OnDraw()

    def OnMouseDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        self.x, self.y = self.lastx, self.lasty = evt.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, evt):
        self.ReleaseMouse()

    def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            self.lastx, self.lasty = self.x, self.y
            self.x, self.y = evt.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh(False)

class CubeCanvas(MyCanvasBase):
    def InitGL(self):
        # set viewing projection
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glFrustum(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0)

        # position viewer
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -2.0)

        # position object
        glRotatef(self.y, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glRotatef(self.x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

    def OnDraw(self):
        # clear color and depth buffers
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        # draw six faces of a cube
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0,-1.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0,-1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glEnd()

        if self.size is None:
            self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        w, h = self.size
        w = max(w, 1.0)
        h = max(h, 1.0)
        xScale = 180.0 / w
        yScale = 180.0 / h
        glRotatef((self.y - self.lasty) * yScale, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef((self.x - self.lastx) * xScale, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        self.SwapBuffers()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class RunDemoApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)

    def OnInit(self):
        canvasClass = eval('CubeCanvas')

        cx = 0

        frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'CubeCanvas', size=(400,400), pos=(cx,400))

        # adding panel with sizer for both canvas
        panel = wx.Panel(frame, -1)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # adding first canvas
        canvas1 = canvasClass(panel) # CubeCanvas(frame) or ConeCanvas(frame); frame passed to         MyCanvasBase
        self.sizer.Add(canvas1, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)

        # adding second canvas
        self.canvas = CanvasPanel(panel)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)

        panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        panel.Fit()

        frame.Show(True)

        self.frame = frame
        return True

    def OnExitApp(self, evt):
        self.frame.Close(True)

    def OnCloseFrame(self, evt):
        if hasattr(self, "window") and hasattr(self.window, "ShutdownDemo"):
            self.window.ShutdownDemo()
        evt.Skip()

app = RunDemoApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just created something similar to this, and managed to get it working, I had to take a few steps back and look at the whole picture to understand.