# Can a matplotlib chart be interactive?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to know if a `matplotlib` chart be interactive, ie when you right click on a graph bar, a context menu opens, then you click one of the menu items and change the value of `y` value or you drag the top edge of the bar with mouse and it becomes taller etc,

In other words, can a matplotlib chart act like a GUI?

Answer (score 2):

yep, though I should warn you: matplotlib isn't the best choice for interactive tasks. Depends on your tasks you may face performance or UX issues..

Take a look at the [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/). It was designed for the creation of complex interactive plots.

[image: Chaco]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

---

Matplotlib is based on Tkinter, so you can do all sorts GUI related things with it. For an example of how you can embed matplotlib in a Tkinter GUI see here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html

Similarly for the functionality you are describing, you require plots that know when they've been clicked on (or mouse-overed) and that you can add callback events to. For that, the first place to look would be `picker` events:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html

Comment: Thanks, but can I pop-up a right-click menu when I click on for example a bar? If yes, can this chart be placed on a wxpython GUI?

Comment: The right-click menu would probably require some custom code. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898115/wxpython-with-matplotlib and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014210/python-tkinter-app-adding-a-right-click-context-menu

Comment: [Right click menu](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Menus.py) is very easy to do with PySimpleGUI (based on tkinter). There is also some [demo code](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms) how to use PySimpleGUI with Matplotlib (see Demo_Matplotlib_*.py).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to some of the other ideas I would propose the [Ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html). For me it is the easiest way to do some of the things your asking about without having to get into Tkinter etc.

From Ipython 2.* onward there are interactive widgets allowing you to interact with the kernel from a GUI. I am not an expert in any sense so it is probably best explain by [Fernando Perez himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=XFw1JVXKJss#t=7219).

Here is an example of interaction when solving the Lorenz differential equation demonstrating a chaotic system. This is accessible in the example of the ipython directory.

[image]