# embedding matplotlib figure and change its size

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I had the same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel).
It works, but this figure shall not cover the whole frame; so I changed size and position of his panel. Problem now is, that my figure still has the same size of my frame and therefore I only changed the panelsize, my figure gets "cut". How can I solve this?
Example for better understanding: My Frame is 800x600 and my figure shall only have the size 400x300 inside this frame.

edit:

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Pyramid App",size=(800,600),pos=((wx.DisplaySize()[0]-800)/2,(wx.DisplaySize()[1]-600)/2),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        self.PageThree = pageThree(self)

class pageThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,525))
        self.myparent=parent
        self.pageThree=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,525)) # put some elements at this panel
        self.pylabfigure = wx.Panel(self,size=(440,420),pos=(350,105)) # this is the panel for my figure
        self.drawPylabFigure()
        self.draw()

    def drawPylabFigure(self):
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.pylabfigure, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        #example drawing
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an idea of how to do it.
Main thing to have into account it to put your panels/canvas organized by one sizer.
Also, if the canvas has to fill his side there is not need to put it in a panel.

```
import wx
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FCW
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Pyramid App",size=(800,600),
                           pos=((wx.DisplaySize()[0]-800)/2,(wx.DisplaySize()[1]-600)/2),
                           style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        self.PageThree = pageThree(self)

class pageThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,525))
        self.myparent=parent
        self.pageThree=wx.Panel(self, size=(500,525))
        self.drawPyFigure()
        self.draw()

    def drawPyFigure(self):
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FCW(self, -1, self.figure)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.pageThree, 0)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you want `self.figure = Figure(figsize=(400 / 80.0, 300 / 80.0))`.

You need to specify the size of the figure (by default 8 inches wide by 6 inches tall) and/or the dpi of the figure (by default, 80 for on-screen display).

However, be aware that the size of the figure *on-screen* depends purely on the total number of pixels (in other words, `width_inches*dpi x height_inches*dpi`).  For that reason, if we want a figure to be a specific number of pixels, we need to convert that to "inches" (which have nothing to do with the figure's display size if it's displayed on-screen) by dividing the number of pixels by the figure's dpi.

Comment: Did you tested it? When I change this line you have posted, nothing changes. I testet it with several parameters, but my image looks always the same.