# Embedding Seaborn plot in WxPython panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, seaborn, kernel-density

I would like to ask how I could embed a seaborn figure in `wxPython` panel.

Similarly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel), I want to embed an external figure in a `wxPython` panel. I would like a specific panel of my `wxPython` GUI to plot the density contours of my data based on bandwidth values of a Gaussian kernel, according to Seaborn's [kdeplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) function, along with a scatter plot of the data points. Here is an example of what I would like to be plotted in the panel: [image: example]

Until now, I have managed to get what I want in a separate figure out of the `wxPython` panel.Is it possible to embed a seaborn plot in a `wxPython` panel or should find an alternative way to implement what I want?

Below is the specific part of my code that generates the plot in case it is needed:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig = self._view_frame.figure

data = np.loadtxt(r'data.csv',delimiter=',')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.cla()
sns.kdeplot(data, bw=10, kernel='gau',  cmap="Reds")
ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1], color='r')

fig.canvas.draw()
```

This part of the code plots in the wxPython panel the scattered data points and creates an external figure for the density contours. But, if I try `ax.sns.kdeplot(...)` I get the error

> Attribute Error: AxesSubplot object has not attribute .sns

I don't know if I can embed a Seaborn figure in `wxPython` panel or I  should try implement it in another way. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seaborn (`sns`) uses MPL, but it's a completely separate library. `ax.sns` makes no sense.You want to pass `ax` to the `sns.kdeplot` function.

Comment: I did exactly that and it works like a charm. I noticed on the function's [page](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) that it accepts such a parameter. More specifically, the `ax` parameter shows the **axis** to plot on. So, in my case I dealt with my problem by doing the following: `sns.kdeplot(data, **ax=ax**, bw=10, kernel='gau',  cmap="Reds")`. Thanks you very much :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about wxPython but if you want to plot onto a specific axes use the `ax` keyword argument.

Comment: Actually, I did not notice on the function's [page](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) that it accepts such a parameter. As it can be seen, `seaborn.kdeplot(data, data2=None, shade=False, vertical=False, kernel='gau', bw='scott', gridsize=100, cut=3, clip=None, legend=True, cumulative=False, shade_lowest=True, **ax=None** , **kwargs)` the `ax` parameter shows the **axis** to plot on. So, in my case I dealt with my problem by doing the following: `sns.kdeplot(data, **ax=ax**, bw=10, kernel='gau',  cmap="Reds")`. Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 2):

I never used Seaborn but I guess because the doc says "Seaborn is a Python visualization library based on matplotlib", you can probably use MPL class called FigureCanvasWxAgg.

Here's a sample code for embedding a MPL figure in wxPython.

```
import numpy as np
import wx

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg

import seaborn

class test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main frame')

        # just a normal MPL "Figure" object
        figure = Figure(None)
        # Place a widget to hold MPL figure. no sizer because this is the only widget
        fc = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, figure)

        # your plotting code here, this can be sns calls i think
        subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)
        subplot.plot(np.arange(10))

        # Lastly show them
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(0)
    testframe = test()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You could probably just replace the plotting code with sns stuff and just make sure to plot on "Figure" object from MPL.

PS. Out of interest, I pip installed it and just importing seaborn already changed the style of MPL. So, it seems working. Because of matplotlib.use call, you will want to import seaborn after MPL imports.

[image]

Comment: Seaborn's [kdeplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) accepts as an argument the **axis** to plot on. This is the `ax` parameter. In my case, I dealt with my problem by doing the following: `sns.kdeplot(data, ax=ax, bw=10, kernel='gau', cmap="Reds")`. In the code you posted above, this can be done by `sns.kdeplot(yourdata, ax=subplot ,bw=10, kernel='gau', cmap="Reds")`. This was initially my problem, I could not find a way and make sure to plot in wxpython's figure(axis). Thanks. :)