# Combine plot and grid in WxPython GUI Example

Tags: user-interface, layout, matplotlib, grid, wxpython

Currently I'm developing a GUI in WxPython.

I have created a lineplot using matplotib and a gridview of the underlying data. However, as I run the program, the grid and the plot are loaded into separate windows. I'm looking for examples or tutorials on how to integrate different items into a single window. 
Does anyone know any good example or tutorials on this? I cannot find a clear example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code [Embedding a matplotlib figure inside a WxPython panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel?rq=1)

Basically, to hold a matplotlib figure you can use `FigureCanvasWxAgg` which can be imported like:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
```

and, you will do the normal plotting on `Figure` instance of MPL.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

and put this Figure on FigureCanvasWxAgg which can be placed on a panel together with your grid using sizer.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I used matplotlib with wx to plot some histograms, this solution  maybe can help you to solve your problem. The code is inherited from a panel, and you need to add this component like a panel. To set the data use the function SetData.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class HistogramPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(-1, -1))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.rootSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rootSizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.rootSizer)

        self.FitInside()
        self.Layout()

    def SetData(self, values, color="black", linewidth=1):
        self.axis.clear()
        self.axis.plot(values, color=color, linewidth=linewidth)
        self.axis.set_xlim([0, 256])
        self.Layout()
```

Comment: just as a side note, there is `set_ydata` method for faster update of an existing plot. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4098938/566035. but this will not take care of data range change, autoscaling etc. so, not a general solution like your code snippet.