# How do I add a user input box for wxPython? And a second plot tab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Completely new to wxpython so my question is on this thread ([Embedding a matplotlib figure inside a WxPython panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel))

How would I add an entry box for the user to enter a value or string? Say 6.0 instead of 3.0 in the xrange value and they click compute again? Or they enter a string that imports a file?

Second question, how can I make 2 tabs for the plots? Tab 1 has a plot and tab 2 has another plot?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

So I got the tabs part to work with this code, but now unsure how to give users the ability to input data for the plots.

```
import wx
import wx.aui
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as mplCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2Wx as mplToolbar
# initialization code: create a basic Wx application
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
framelist = [] # list of frames (windows) created here

def MakePlotWindow(DisableDelete=False, size=(600,600), **kw):
    ''' Create a plot window with an empty notebook widget for plots includes a sizer at top
    for placement of wx widgets
    Input:
       size: the dimensions of the plot window in pixels (defaults to 600x600)
       other keyword args for wx.Frame are allowed
    Output:
       returns the name of the created panel (<panel>)
         Use <panel>.Parent to access the frame
         Note that <panel>.topsizer is a sizer above the plot where wx objects can be placed
         and <panel>.bottomsizer is a sizer below the plot where wx objects can be placed
    '''
    kw["size"] = size
    plotter = PlotNotebook(id, DisableDelete, **kw)
    global framelist
    framelist.append(plotter.frame)        
    return plotter

def ShowPlots():
    '''Call ShowPlots after all plots are defined to cause the plots to be displayed
    and to enter the event loop so that widgets respond to mouse clicks, etc.
    '''
    for frame in framelist:
        frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

class PlotNotebook(wx.Panel):
    ''' defines a panel in a independent frame (window). Call from MakePlotWindow'''
    def __init__(self, id, DisableDelete=False, **kw):
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, **kw) # create a frame
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, self.frame) # create the panel
        # note the above places this panel inside the new frame
        # create a notebook widget:
        if DisableDelete:
            self.nb = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( 
                self,
                style=wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE ^ wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB
                # turns off the delete tab
            ) 
        else:
            self.nb = wx.aui.AuiNotebook(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # create a sizer for the notebook
        self.topsizer =  wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # a place for misc wx items
        sizer.Add(self.topsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND) # place the widget box in the sizer
        sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND) # place the notebook in the sizer
        self.bottomsizer =  wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # a place for misc wx items
        sizer.Add(self.bottomsizer, 0, wx.EXPAND) # place the widget box in the sizer
        self.SetSizer(sizer) # associate the sizer with the panel created by class

    def AddPlotTab(self,name="plot"):
        '''Adds a plot tab to the panel
        Input:
           name: a string that is placed on the plot tab
        Output:
           returns the wx.Panel object that contains the the new plot. Note that
              <panel>.figure is the plot figure
              <panel>.canvas is the plot canvas
              <panel>.toolbar is the toolbar object
              <panel>.topsizer is a sizer above the plot where wx objects can be placed
        '''
        page = Plot(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(page,name)
        return page

    def ReusePlotTab(self,name="plot"):
        '''Reuses a plot tab on the panel, if a tab with the selected name exists. Uses the
        first one if more than one such tab exists. Creates a tab with the name, if one is
        not found.
        Input:
           name: a string that is placed on the plot tab
        Output:
           returns the wx.Panel object that contains the the new plot. Note that
              <panel>.figure is the plot figure
              <panel>.canvas is the plot canvas
              <panel>.toolbar is the toolbar object
              <panel>.topsizer is a sizer above the plot where wx objects can be placed
        '''
        for PageNum in range(self.nb.GetPageCount()):
            if name == self.nb.GetPageText(PageNum):
                Page = self.nb.GetPage(PageNum)
                return Page
        return self.AddPlotTab(name)         # not found, create a new tab

    def RaisePlotTab(self,name="plot"):
        '''Raises a plot tab on the panel so that the plot is visible. Uses the
        first one if more than one such tab exists. Does nothing if no such tab is found'''
        for PageNum in range(self.nb.GetPageCount()):
            if name == self.nb.GetPageText(PageNum):
                self.nb.SetSelection(PageNum)
                return

class Plot(wx.Panel):
    ''' Defines a panel containing a plot etc to be placed in a notebook widget
    Note that this is expected to be called only from PlotNotebook.AddPlotTab
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, dpi = None, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, **kwargs)
        # create a figure with an associated canvas & toolbar
        self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=dpi) 
        self.canvas = mplCanvas(self, -1, self.figure) # wxPanel object containing plot
        self.toolbar = mplToolbar(self.canvas) # toolbar object
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.topsizer =  wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # a place for misc wx items
        # put the canvas, toolbar & topsizer in a sizer and associate the sizer
        # with self (the main panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.topsizer,0,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0 , wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy import arange, sin, pi  
    # create the first plot window
    plotter = MakePlotWindow(size=(700,700), DisableDelete=True,)
    plotter.Parent.SetTitle("Title for 1st Plot Window")
    # add a plot to the window with a straight line
    page1 = plotter.AddPlotTab('Plot1')
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2 * pi * t)
    page1.figure.gca().plot(t,s,color='red')
    # code to respond to a key press inside the window
    #page1.figure.gca().set_title("Press any key inside plot") # plot title
    #page1.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onKeyPress) 
    # create a second plot on the 1st window and raise it 
    page2 = plotter.AddPlotTab('Plot2')
    page2.figure.gca().plot(range(10),[i**2 for i in range(10)],'+-')
    plotter.RaisePlotTab('Plot2')
    # everything is done, display the plots and start the event loop
    ShowPlots()
```