# matplotlib doesn't show figures after converting to exe file

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, pyinstaller

Everything looks OK if I just run the scripts in Pycharm. It will show the plots.
However, after I convert the scripts into exe file. It can save the plots, but it won't show any plot. The most weird thing is that it will re-open another exe file.

Thanks, really appreciate if someone know the root cause.

Comment: Somehow it is fixed by 1) adding matplotlib.use('WXagg')  2) not using multiprocessing.

Comment: I am pretty sure `WXagg` is required to embed matplotlib in wxPython. I suspect the tool you were using to create your executable wasn't picking up everything it needed from matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, calling `matplotlib.use('WXAgg')` is necessary, but there is another step: matplotlib has a backend object you need to import manually to paint a figure in wx: `matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg`. This creates a figure canvas object inside a wx.panel of your choosing.

[This answer contains a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel). Furthermore, you can look up the actual object in [matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_wxagg_api.html#module-matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg), then proceed to look at their [artist tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html), which covers how to use matplotlib in applications rather well.