# Matplotlib FuncAnimation does not update the plot embedded in wx Panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am trying to update a plot with serial data with matplotlib FuncAnimation. I am using the following example to embed the plot in a wx app.

[Embedding a matplotlib figure inside a WxPython panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel)

However, the plot is not updated and only the initial plot is displayed. [image]

In fact, the update function is never executed which is checked with print statements in try and except blocks. You may see the script here.

```
import wx

from matplotlib.figure import Figure as Fig
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar

from collections import deque
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mlp
import numpy as np

# Class that inherits wx.Panel. The purpose is to embed it into 
# a wxPython App. That part can be seen in main()
class Serial_Plot(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, strPort, id=-1, dpi=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, id=id, **kwargs)
        self.figure  = Fig(figsize=(20,20))
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.plot_data, = self.ax.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()
        # Serial communication
        self.ser = serial.Serial(strPort, 115200)
        # Serial data initialized as deque. The serial readings from arduino
        # are set to be one value per line.
        self.vals = deque()
        # matplotlib function animation
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.update, 
                                   interval=20)
        plt.show()
        self.close
    def update(self, i):
        try:
            print('trying')
            # read serial line
            data = float(self.ser.readline().decode('utf-8'))
            print(data)
            self.vals.append(data)
            # update plot data
            self.plot_data.set_data(range(len(self.vals)), self.vals)
        except:
            print('oops')
            pass
        return self.plot_data

    def close(self):
        # close serial
        self.ser.flush()
        self.ser.close()

def main():

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "WX APP!")
    demo_plot = Serial_Plot(frame,'COM3')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my previous answer([Embedding matplotlib FuncAnimation in wxPython: Unwanted figure pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047934/embedding-matplotlib-funcanimation-in-wxpython-unwanted-figure-pop-up/52062669#52062669)), trying to use `animation.FuncAnimation()` and `plt.show()` within wxpython is not going to work, because you have 2 main.loops.
If we cull all of the wx.python from your original question and pare it down to the basics, we get this:

```
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
vals = deque()
figure  = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1000), ylim=(0, 5000))
plot_data, = ax.plot([], [])

def update(i):
    data = float(random.randint(1000, 5000))
    vals.append(data)
    plot_data.set_data(range(len(vals)), vals)
    return plot_data

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It works because the `animation` function is controlled by `plt.show()` i.e. matplotlib but once you introduce wxpython, it controls the main.loop not matplotlib.
I believe that you will have to use a wxpython `timer` to control the serial device read, feeding data into the plot, as demonstrated in my previous answer.
[Embedding matplotlib FuncAnimation in wxPython: Unwanted figure pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047934/embedding-matplotlib-funcanimation-in-wxpython-unwanted-figure-pop-up/52062669#52062669)